# memory management in class method in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, class-method

I have problems with memory in my class methods.

I have created a class method which will fetch records from core data and return a NSArray.

These are the problem i face:

1. sometimes the data is returned properly, it works fine.
2. sometimes it returns a CFArray

   a.how to deal with with type of array??

   b.what does this type of array mean??
3. sometimes the array becomes a invalid object when returned to the class which called the method

But in all the ways NSArray inside the method has data.  Why does it react in different ways every time? Is there any way to manage this problem?

Code snippet used:

```
+(NSArray *)retrieveEvents

{

    NSArray *arrData;

    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [APPDEL.managedObjectModel fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"fetchEvents"];
    arrData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[APPDEL.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error]];

    return arrData;
}
```

Comment: CFArray is essentially the same as NSArray.  (the former can contain c pointers).  Treat it like an NSArray and it will be fine.

Comment: hi, no im not using ARC. CFArray when it comes, the app crashes. Should i allocate the NSArray?? If so, when to release it?? I cant use autorelease since this method is called more than 50times in my code (changing the entities names).

Comment: Can you post the console output at the crash?  I think you're seeing the CF array correlated with the crash, not causing it.  I don't think it's memory, either.  As coded, it's returning an autoreleased array.  Callers can inspect that array and forget it, or save it somewhere and retain it.  Seems right.  My guess is that the crash is due to an error in the fetch.  The console output will help.

Comment: i don get any data in console. it crashes in "main" method.

Comment: Try adding an exceptions breakpoint.  Go to breakpoint navigator, hit plus sign at the bottom left, break on "all exceptions".

Comment: yes.. i tried it, tats the reason i got to know it crashed in main method.